# Can't modify the icon of DXRibbonWindow in WPF

Tags: wpf, dxribbonwindow

I tried to custome the icon of `DXRibbonWindow` by adding `Icon=<Icon url>` in `DXRibbonWindow` tag, like this:

`<DXRibbonWindow Icon="<Icon Url>" ... ></RXRibbonWindow>`

but it doesn't work, the icon remains as default, how can i custom the window icon?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a URL or a file path? I believe the property will only work with a correctly formatted file path to a suitable file type.

Here is an example from DevExpress for reference:

```
Icon="/WpfApplication9;component/Images/webcam_32.ico">
```